# Best way to convert null padded but not null terminated fixed length character array to std::string

Tags: c++

What is the best way to convert fixed size character arrays that may or may not be null terminated to std::strings. Below is my best guess but would be interested to hear if there are any other options.

```
std::string ToString(const char* buffer, const std::size_t bufferSize)
{
    return std::string(buffer, strnlen_s(buffer, bufferSize));
}

int main()
{
    char buffer1[4] = { 't','e', 's', 't' };
    char buffer2[5] = { 'o','n', 'e', '\0', '\0' };
    auto s1 = ToString(buffer1, sizeof(buffer1));
    auto s2 = ToString(buffer2, sizeof(buffer2));
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What do you want `s2` to look like?

Comment: What's the problem ?

Comment: My code works. I just wondered if there is some built in STL function function that I overlooked for this. Also, I wanted to post this example because it is currently difficult to find this out on stackoverflow and I wanted to help others.

Answer (score 1):

Your implementation is great as is.

The only other thing you might want to do is provide another overload that can infer the size from the array, for the cases where the length is known at compile time:

```
#include <string>
#include <string.h>
#include <iostream>

template <int n> std::string arrayToString(const char(&raw)[n]) {
    return std::string(raw, strnlen_s(raw, n));
}

int main()
{
    char buffer1[4] = { 't', 'e', 's', 't' };
    char buffer2[5] = { 'o', 'n', 'e', '\0', '\0' };
    std::string s1 = arrayToString(buffer1);
    std::string s2 = arrayToString(buffer2);

    std::cout << s1 << std::endl;  // test
    std::cout << s2 << std::endl;  // one
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `strnlen_s` is an optional function for compilers to support , so changes are probably in order if portability is desired